# «Приятно удивлён» — управление

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Какой вариант написания будет правильным с лексической точки зрения? Или оба варианта верны?

1. Приятно удивлен от LEGO.
2. Приятно удивлен LEGO.

Вот этот предлог ОТ нужен ли?

Answer (score 2):

• Управление в русском языке (Д. Э. Розенталь):
[удивлён](https://gufo.me/dict/rection_rosenthal/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD) — ***чем***. *Удивлен его странным поведением.*

• Правильно без предлога (и только "чем?"):
**Приятно удивлён LEGO** (если речь идет о стилизованном названии компании);
**Приятно удивлён лего** (если речь идет о конструкторе).

В орфографическом словаре:
лего, нескл., с. (игра лего).

• Слово *LEGO* (*лего*) не склоняется, поэтому его падеж в предложении определяется только по задаваемому вопросу:
удивлён ("чем?" творительный падеж) — тёплым пальто, красивым метро, военным атташе, дорогим лего.

• Примеры из Нацкорпуса

*...Кирилл был **приятно удивлен** его **образованностью*** (Михаил Веллер. Белый ослик).

*Я был **приятно удивлен** и очарован комедийным **даром** артиста, его **легкостью** и **непринужденностью*** (Эльдар Рязанов. Подведенные итоги).

*...он был **приятно удивлен радостью**...* (Максим Горький. Жизнь Клима Самгина).

Answer (score 1):

*От* категорически не годится.

Удивиться (удивляться) кому-чему и на кого-что.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Приятно удивлен* (*чем? чему?* - от контекста) *LEGO.*